# Should I remove padding on laminate flooring before gluing it to steps?

Tags: stairs, adhesive, laminate-floor

I have some laminate flooring that I'm installing on a few steps that lead into my sunk-floor family room.

The flooring is intended for a floating installing, but I know that on steps I have to glue and nail it to keep it stable.

The manufacturer appears to say nothing about stair installation. I read through the warranty/install guide and it only address the floor installation. It excludes certain things (i.e. ceilings), but doesn't exclude stairs. Here is the [product page](https://www.lumberliquidators.com/ll/c/pad-Boa-Vista-Brazilian-Cherry-Laminate-Flooring-Dream-Home-10BV-CL/10021523).

The flooring I bought comes with an attached pad.  Do I have to remove that before installing?

If I don't remove it, I'm concerned that the bond won't be a strong as needed, or that the padding will allow shifting.

If I do remove it, I'm concerned that it will make it a slightly different height than the [stair nosing](https://www.lumberliquidators.com/ll/c/Boa-Vista-Brazilian-Cherry-Flush-Stair-Nose-A10BVFSN/10038361).

Comment: How thick is the attached pad? Is it thin enough that the thickness of the glue will almost compensate?

Comment: @spuck:  Uncompressed, it's 1/16".

Comment: We'd have to know more about the product. There's not a universal answer. What does the manufacturer say?

Comment: @isherwood:  The manufacturer appears to say nothing about stair installation.  I read through the warranty/install guide and it only address the floor installation.  It excludes certain things (i.e. ceilings), but doesn't exclude stairs.  Here is the product page:  https://www.lumberliquidators.com/ll/c/pad-Boa-Vista-Brazilian-Cherry-Laminate-Flooring-Dream-Home-10BV-CL/10021523

Comment: Put it in your question, please. Also revise to describe how you intend to nail this stuff. You're in experimental territory here and all information you have to share is helpful.

Comment: The link you provided is to the retailer, not the manufacturer. Look up the manufacturer's web site & use their "contact us" link to ask them. Not trying to put you off, but if you're concerned enough to ask (and a possibly moving surface on stairs seems to be enough reason to be concerned), go to the _source_, not some internet strangers, no matter how well intentioned they may be.

Comment: i glued the bottom pad on my stairs about a year ago; no problems so far.

Comment: Not posting this as an answer since I don't know this is correct, but I think using a thin bead of construction adhesive (or whatever glue you are proposing) will be at least 1/16". Maybe I don't understand exactly what you're looking at, but I'm not sure I would want to install a "nosing" at the edge of a stair that's measurablely taller than the tread; it sounds like a potential trip hazard.

Comment: @spuck I believe that's the concern mentioned in the last sentence of the question, "If I do remove it, I'm concerned that it will make it a slightly different height than the stair nosing."

Comment: @FreeMan I understand. I'm trying to picture it in my head: by "nosing", I'm envisioning something designed to go up the vertical face of the tread, wrapping over and on top of the exposed edge of the flooring on the tread itself. Even if the backing pad were left in place, I'm not sure I would want that extra lump on the edge of my stair tread. I've seen some awful looking trim pieces designed to cover huge expansion gaps on floating floors; without a picture or a link, it's hard to know if this is one of them...

Comment: @FreeMan:  I added a link to the stair nosing, if you're curious.